# Error While setting query_cache_size in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-cache

When I tried to set query_cache_size in mysql, But it shows an warning and reset the cache size to 0

```
 +---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1282 | Query cache failed to set size 41984; new query cache size is 0 |
+-
--------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried the query

> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 41984;

I am using MySQL **Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)**

So please help me to set query cache size..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first set `query_cache_type = 1` in my.cnf and restart MySQL and then set query_cache_size.

Please have a look at  [**How to set Query cache in MySQL.**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/enable-the-query-cache-in-mysql-to-improve-performance.html)